# Why is there strange behaviour on IE11?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

It seems that there is an issue with my deployed version of a jQuery Mobile site. Running on local machine, it looks ok.

However when deploying to a testserver, the ui of jQuery Mobile runs into a problem (as shown in the picture below).  I have tested the deployed webpage on both IE11 and Chrome. On Chrome it looks exactly like the local hosted version, so it's only "strange" iu on IE11.

[image]

The HTML source is of course identical on both version, excepts the path to the files (css/js), but again on Chrome it works on both 'versions'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1" />
  <!-- Styles -->
  <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="/Content/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="/Scripts/Bundles/jquery?v=_evuqQpQzfiv74i_e2xne0q8qDFolKEd-XnaMgC-rWw1"></script>

  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-nb-NO.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/Bundles/jqueryMobile?v=sCRDQK2ukYmfF8e6gB7crpqBhGj3REAZ0OWnxCy4ozU1"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
      <a href="/" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>

      <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

<a href='#' data-role="button"><div><div class="btn-icon-text">Button 1</div></div></a>
<a href='#' data-role="button"><div><div class="btn-icon-text">Button 2</div></div></a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
      <div id="leftBottomContent" style="float: left"><a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn">back</a></div>
      <div id="rightBottomContent" style="float: right"></div>
      <div id="centerBottomContent" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; margin-top: 15px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've checked using Fiddler that the requests from the server are ok. Can anyone point me in a direction to figure this one out?

Comment: try removing `/` before `/Scripts` and `/Content`. Seems wrong path. And check what the console says. You may be getting error messages if your path is wrong.

Comment: The path is generated by ASP.NET -> href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css")" and if I check the paths using Chrome (view source) they are found. But in Chrome it works perfect.

Comment: locally deployed could also mean problems with Compatibility view, could you check developer center inside IE11 to make sure no compatibility mode was selected?

Comment: The compability mode was set on intranet sites, which solved my issue by turning it off. Thanks! If you add an answer to this thread, I'll set it to answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, setting compatibility mode on your own PC fixes the issue for you, but how about for anybody else who tries to use your application?

You can add a `meta` header to your Layout that will force compatibility mode and in turn make it so others do not have the same issue that you're seeing

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`

be sure to add this immediately after the `<head>` tag in your html

Answer (score 0):

Turning off compability mode on intranet sites solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your header page, which makes users to use compatible mode by default when application is used:

```
    <%
    response.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge");
    %>
```